# Can service live longer than application

Tags: android, android-service

In my android application I am using a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which is spawning a thread as a worker. Sometimes I observed the application is killed but the thread is still trying to refer some of the values which are no more available.

Can android decide to kill my application leaving the service still running?

I am stopping the thread in onDestroy() method of my service and hence want to know when Android kills the application, would it call Service:onDestroy().

Comment: When your service or any thread of the app is running, it means the app is running.

Comment: Have you checked if onDestroy() is actually called?

Comment: I leave the app for few hours in background. When I click it from the recent apps, I observe the app is being launched from the launcher activity and not resumed from the latest activity opened. Doesn't it mean the app was killed? But I also observed the thread is running...

Comment: @Wayofhope, If the *app is launched from launcher activity*, it means activity was destroyed. It doesn't mean that each and every component of the app was destroyed. But when application is killed, android will surely destroy the service, and onDestroy method will be called.

Answer (score 1):

All the applications in Android runs as a separate process similar to a linux process. So if your service is running in a separate process then the Android might decide to shut down a process at some point, when memory is low and required by other processes that are more immediately serving the user. Application components running in the process that's killed are consequently destroyed. A process is started again for those components when there's again work for them to do.

When deciding which processes to kill, the Android system weighs their relative importance to the user. For example, it more readily shuts down a process hosting activities that are no longer visible on screen, compared to a process hosting visible activities. The decision whether to terminate a process, therefore, depends on the state of the components running in that process. The rules used to decide which processes to terminate is discussed below.

Also you can control that if your service can run in the same process as of your application or in a separate process by using the  android:process attribute in the manifest.

For more information You can read about processes and threads on below link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html